STB Simulation of Capacitive Feedback Amplifier
I am trying to simulation the loop gain of two capacitive feedback amplifier circuits. The two circuits shown below only differ by the opamp used. The top figure uses a single-stage opamp, while the bottom figure uses a two-stage opamp. The diffstbprobes are placed at the same position for the two circuits as shown.


The simulation result for the top circuit is given below:

The simulation result for the bottom circuit is given below:

I'm not sure why the bottom circuit phase response started from -180 deg instead of 180 deg like the top circuit. Could you please show me the reason behind this?
Thank you very much

They are equivalent isn't it? 180deg = -180deg

@Sai  Thank you very much for your reply. Yes they seem to be equivalent. However, I'm not sure why the second one started at -180 deg.

I can only guess that if the phase increases at low frequencies, phase starts at -180 else starts at 180. You can see that in the second curve, phase slightly goes up before going down
